# CSS styles for autosize and react-select

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I am trying to duplicate [this](https://jsfiddle.net/z3a9usj5/5/) autosize ability onto v2 components. But I tried to replace the classes with my own custom-class:

```
.select-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.select-custom-class .select-custom-class__multi-value {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.select-custom-class .select-custom-class__menu {
  text-align: left;
}

.select-custom-class__placeholder, .select-custom-class__control .select-custom-class__value-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.select-custom-class__control, .select-custom__clear-indicator, .select-custom-class__dropdown-indicator {
  display: inherit;
}

.select-custom-class .select-custom-class__multi-value {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.select-custom-class__clear-indicators {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 20px;
}
.select-custom-class__dropdown-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

Instead of getting the component to autosize, I ended up getting a really small component. Please help me with this css mapping. Also, I cannot see any of the menu css style names, how can I get a list of them? I am trying to guess from [this](https://deploy-preview-2289--react-select.netlify.com/styles) list.